# Java in Android, Problems in array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to use the array in my android program.

I did this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView[ ] answer = { new TextView(this) };
```

and, I tried to do use `answer[0]`

but it gives me errors. Is there any problems with me initializing the arrays?

### (I want to create, and initialize them at once)

Guys thank you.. figured it out by help!

I did

> TextView[]  answer;
>   in Main

and did

> TextView[] answer = {new TextView(this)};
>   in On create

this made me able to use answer in other methods! thank you guyz!

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @codeMan I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
TextView[] answer = { new TextView(this) };
```

needs to be in an instance method such as [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)). If you need to access it outside the method declare it as a class member variable:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView[ ] answer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       answer = new TextView[] { new TextView(this) };
    }
   ....
}
```

Comment: would you explain about it a little bit more?
it is confusing for me(just started).

Comment: Looks like that statement is in the class block rather than in a method. Therefore you won't have `this` instance...

Comment: Oh!... OK! Thank you.... Now I feel like I'm understanding it.... So, what should I do know?

Comment: Wait.. what does "this" state? what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions.... So, what does **this** mean in these kinds of situation?

Comment: [`this` is a reference to the current object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: would it work if i do this? **TextView[]  answer = {new TextView(null)};**

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the instance of `MainActivity` on which `onCreate()` has been called.

In general, from the [Java Language Specification, 15.8.3:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

```
The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method, instance initializer or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.

When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed. The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs. At run time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the class C or any subclass of C.
```

Comment: so what does **this** mean in these kinds of situations?

Comment: In java, this is a reference variable that refers to the current object

Comment: and object should be initialised first so in your case becuase you are extending Activity u need to initialise the new Textview(this) inside the method which is called first when compilers compile the java file so you have to do the  your code inside the OnCreate() method in your case

Comment: But, how can i use answer[?] in other methods?

Comment: you can use by calling like answer[o].setText("HelloWorld"); for doing any changes

Comment: but you have to call these stuffs inside Oncreate() Method

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
      TextView[] answers;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       answers = new TextView[]{new TextView(this)};

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined as:

```
TextView[] answer = new TextView[]{new TextView(this)};
```

Comment: what error you are getting? TextView cannot be resolved to a type? if so then have you have to import this : import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: I'm not sure it is giving me like tons of them. It works when I create the "answer" and create the object "answer[0]" in "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)".